# Custom attributes in UiBinder widgets

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I'm using GWT and UiBinder for my app, and I'm trying to do this

`<g:TextBox ui:field="searchBox" styleName="{style.searchBox}" placeholder="search" />`

But the custom `placeholder` attribute won't work because there isn't a `setPlaceholder` method on `TextBox` - I need to this:

`searchBox.getElement().setAttribute("placeholder", "search");`

back in the java code. Any ideas on how to do this in UiBinder itself? I suppose I could change it over to a normal input element and try to grab a reference and its value, but I'd rather not go down that road.

Comment: Afaik this is not possible (as you said, you need a setter method for it). Why not setting the attribute in the constructor of the corresponding view class right after calling `initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this))`? Edit: or write your own placeholder functionality that will work on older browsers too.

Comment: After `initWidget` is where I'm calling the `setAttribute` right now... I don't want to move presentation out of the XML files...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about creating custom `SearchBox` that extends `TextBox` with method `setPlaceholder(String placeholder)` ?

Then in UiBinder:

> `<custom:SearchBox ui:field="searchBox" styleName="{style.searchBox}"
>   placeholder="search" />`

Comment: That's probably what I'll eventually do in this case, but I see it getting more and more difficult to use HTML 5 features that are attribute based :(

Answer (score 8):

About a year after this was asked, I had a need to use custom attributes (placeholder, specifically). So I wrote the following custom `TextField` class that extends `TextBox`, leaving in tact all of the underlying functionality of a GWT `TextBox` including handlers and such. Hope someone stumbles upon this in their searches. :)

```
public class TextField extends TextBox {

  String placeholder = "";

  /**
   * Creates an empty text box.
   */
  public TextField() {}

  /**
   * Gets the current placeholder text for the text box.
   * 
   * @return the current placeholder text
   */
  public String getPlaceholder() {
      return placeholder;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the placeholder text displayed in the text box.
   * 
   * @param placeholder the placeholder text
   */
  public void setPlaceholder(String text) {
      placeholder = (text != null ? text : "");
      getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder", placeholder);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store the placeholder as a java variable, too. You can just use the DOM value directly.