# GWT DateBox Watermark/Placeholder

Tags: gwt, watermark, datebox

I want to set a watermark/placeholder inside of a GWT DateBox. I know how to use onFocus and onBlur to set up a watermark/placeholder in a normal TextBox. I assumed that doing so in a DateBox would be relatively similar. Setting up the text currently looks like this, but does nothing at all.

```
    Datebox box = new DateBox();
    box.getTextBox().setText("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Is there a reason that this would not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine what you were actually talking about here was being able to set placeholder text. I posted a solution for `TextBox` elements [here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939490/custom-attributes-in-uibinder-widgets). The process would be quite similar:

```
public class DateField extends DateBox {

  String placeholder = "";

  /**
   * Creates an empty DateField.
   */
  public DateField() {}

  /**
   * Gets the current placeholder text for the date box.
   * 
   * @return the current placeholder text
   */
  public String getPlaceholder() {
      return placeholder;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the placeholder text displayed in the date box.
   * 
   * @param placeholder the placeholder text
   */
  public void setPlaceholder(String text) {
      placeholder = (text != null ? text : "");
      getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder", placeholder);
  }
}
```

Then replace your `DateBox` objects with `DateField` objects, and you'd just call `someDateField.setPlaceholder("mm/dd/yyyy");`.

Answer (score 1):

```
box.getTextBox().setValue("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Even after trying this, the DateBox shows no text. As a matter of curiosity, what is the difference between setText and setValue in a TextBox (sorry for the noob question)?

Comment: I have just tried it and it works, are you over writing it at some point?

Comment: @chris `setText` is inherited from `HasText`, and really just passes the value through to `setValue`.